# Count number of characters in line

Tags: python, string, count

I need to count the amount of characters in a line.
I have tried various methods that I have found, but they all provide incorrect output.

I have tried:

```
with file as f:
     for line in file:
         chars = len(line)
```

But the output was off by a good 200.

I ended up doing this:

```
with file as f:
for line in f:
    self.length += 1
    self.count = len(list(line.strip('\n')))
```

This returned both the amount of lines, and the amount of chars in the last line.

EDIT:I don't get why I'm being downvoted for asking a question that clearly abides by all the rules.

Comment: Can you show the actual line of text?

Comment: `with file as f:   for line in file:` is incorrect for a few reasons.  Anyway, this approach will only give you the length of the *last* line in the file.

Comment: That code should actually work... what version of python are you using? And are you sure it isn't producing incorrect results?

Comment: Does your text file contains non-latin characters?

Comment: roippi, I checked, and the last line of the file is 200 chars shorter than all of the other ones, so you're right, that will return the last line length.

Comment: Can someone please answer me why this question is "off topic", and why it's such a big deal that you have to downvote me and remove "Python"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are reading lines from a text file.

Why not use .splitlines() or .strip() to append each line to a list?  Then you can use the len( ) function on each list element.

*Edit: wording

Comment: I didn't store each line in a list, because I only need one of the lines, since they are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the length of each line, not just the last, use the following code:

```
with open('file.txt') as myfile:
    for line in file:
        print len(line)
```

### Running:

#### `file.txt`

```
Hello there,

What is your name?

Bye
```

#### Expected Output

```
13
1
19
1
4
```

#### Actual Output

```
>>> with open('file.txt') as myfile:
...     for line in myfile:
...             print len(line)
... 
13
1
19
1
4
>>>
```

If you are wondering why a seemingly epty line would have a length of one, it is because newlines are saved as `'\n'` in python. The actual file looks like:

```
>>> myfile = open('file.txt').read()
>>> myfile
'Hello there,\n\nWhat is your name?\n\nBye\n'
>>>
```

But when you call the `print`, it converts the escape sequences into new lines:

```
>>> myfile = open('file.txt').read()
>>> print myfile
Hello there,

What is your name?

Bye

>>>
```

Comment: I know.

But I don't want to "get" the length of each line, I want to "store" the length of the last line. I know how I could "store" the length of each line, but that would be making my code 499 more times inefficient then it needs to be. Thanks anyway.